# What is a worker in C?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, worker

I'm looking at the `ss` command code and I've seen a function that seems to be passing a function as an argument to another function. But I thought that the way of doing this was declaring a pointer to a function. In the code instead they do the as follow:

```
generic_record_read(fp, tcp_show_line, f, AF_INET6).
```

The prototype of that function is:

```
static int generic_record_read(FILE *fp,
               int (*worker)(char*, const struct filter *, int),
               const struct filter *f, int fam);
```

and the function I think is being passed as a parammeter to `generic_record_read` is `tcp_show_line`, which prototype is:

```
static int tcp_show_line(char *line, const struct filter *f, int family)
```

I do not understand the way of declaring the parmeter `tcp_show_line` in `generic_record_read` as `int (*worker)(char*, const struct filter *, int)`

The types  (`char*, const struct filter *, int`)  correspond with the parameters of `tcp_show_line` but with `int (*worker)` preceding.

All seems that this is a way of passing a function as a parameter because in the implementation of `generic_record_read`, *worked* is used as if it was the function `tcp_show_line`, but I've never seen something like this:

```
static int generic_record_read(FILE *fp,
               int (*worker)(char*, const struct filter *, int),
               const struct filter *f, int fam)
{
//....

    if (worker(line, f, fam) < 0)
        return 0;
//.....
}
```

Am I wrong?

Comment: It's just a function pointer passed as an argument. `worker` is what they chose to name it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you expected, *worker* is a function pointer, which when invoked, takes the following arguments: `char*, const struct filter *, int`. If you haven't seen any of this before, then you obviously haven't worked with [qsort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) or [bsearch](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/bsearch.html), which are standard C functions for sorting and searching. This sort of abstraction is very useful in C.

Answer (score 1):

```
int (*worker)(char*, const struct filter *, int)
```

Says `worker` is a pointer to a function that takes parameter list `(char *, const struct filter *, int)` and returns an `int`. Was that your question?